# How do I keep XElement from encoding a path string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

How do I pass this UTF-8 encoded path to XElement?

C:\Path\To\File\8•26•18.webloc

I am working on this code snippet at the moment.  When I look at the file.FullName it appears correctly as a string but when C# passes it on to XElement it is reencoded to:

C:\Path\To\File\8%EF%80%A226%EF%80%A218.webloc

This then throws the error "Could not find file"

```
foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles("*.webloc",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    try
    {
        if (!file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) && file.Length != 0)
        {
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

            string unicodeUriString = file.FullName;

            Byte[] encodedUriString = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeUriString);

            //string uriString = utf8.GetString(encodedUriString);

            XElement url = XElement.Load(utf8.GetString(encodedUriString));

            IEnumerable<string> partNos = from item in url.Descendants("string")
                                          select (string)item.Value;

            string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName);
            // Write filenames to string
            foreach (var part in partNos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t<DT><A HREF={0}>{1}</A>",part, result); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have been trying to encode the string but this has not worked.

This code works on files without strange characters.

Comment: _"The boxes are a bullet"_ - so is your original text `C:\Path\To\File\8•26•18.webloc`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't figure out how to get that into the question. I have edited the question.

Comment: What is this code supposed to accomplish in the first place? Why go through `XElement` at all? And if you do need an `XElement`, why not just give it `file.FullName` instead of making it interpret a re-encoded string? Once in memory, .NET strings are all UTF-16 (but at the same time the encoding is transparent to you, so it doesn't matter). Likewise, NTFS uses UTF-16 to encode filenames, not UTF-8 (but, again, normally this is transparent to you). Encoding to UTF-8 would be something you'd only need to do in the very last step, when outputting an XML document as bytes.

Comment: That was all just test code.  I was showing my work if you will.  I started with just XElement.Load(file.FullName) and that is where I ran into the error.  I am going through XElement so that I can pull out the "string" element from the XML.  If you can suggest a better way I would gladly try it.

Comment: Just tried `XElement.Load(@"C:\Temp\8•26•18.webloc")` and it loads the file..?

Comment: If nothing else, if file name/URI parsing were an issue, you could use the overload of `XElement.Load` that accepts a `Stream` (`XElement.Load(file.OpenRead(...))`), or explicitly construct an `XmlReader`, or many other ways to get the file contents directly instead of passing the path.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You have done it!  I don't know why passing the path to File.OpenRead works differently but it now works as intended.

Comment: Technically, `XElement.Load` accepts a URI, not a file path. Although local file names are supposed to just "sort of work" when interpreted as URIs (even without being escaped as `file:///` URIs first), I can see ways that this could go wrong.

Comment: @stuartd you are correct that that filename works.  Unfortunately that filename must be encoded differently because it does not show up as the boxes when I cut and paste it. Thanks for your help! I have been a long time lurker and this was my first time reaching out to all you fine folks. I appreciate this community and hope to be a bigger part of it from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the suggestion of @JeroenMostert this code snippet now performs as intended.  Hopefully someone can shed some light as to why the path is passed along differently through `File.OpenRead`

```
foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles("*.webloc",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    try
    {
        if (!file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) && file.Length != 0)
        {
            XElement url = XElement.Load(File.OpenRead(file.FullName));

        IEnumerable<string> partNos = from item in url.Descendants("string")
                                      select (string)item.Value;

        string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName);
        // Write filenames to string
        foreach (var part in partNos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t<DT><A HREF={0}>{1}</A>",part, result); 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `FileInfo` has an `OpenRead` method you can use directly. Furthermore, you should properly dispose of the stream so created (so `using (var fs = file.OpenRead()) { XElement.Load(fs); }`).